# Writing variable to a file using macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I need to write data from a macro to a text file. I am using the below code:

```
VAR_ABC = "Deployment1.txt"
Dim FlName As String
filesize = FreeFile()

Open FlName For Output As #filesize
   Write #filesize, "Hello World!"
   Write #filesize, "" & VAR_ABC;
 Close #filesize
```

I have below questions:

1. The output in my file contains double quotes i.e.
   "Hello World"
   "Deployment1.sh"
   How to get rid of these double quotes in my text file?
2. Is there a way to write multiple lines in a better way(with new line character) than using Write again and again?
3. If I am to use variables, is it mandatory to use them like: "" & VarName. Is it not possible to have only VarName in Write Command.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Write` with `Print`.

```
Sub test()
    VAR_ABC = "Deployment1.txt"
    Dim FlName As String
    filesize = FreeFile()

    Open "C:\Temp\Hello.txt" For Output As #filesize
       Print #filesize, "Hello World!"
       Print #filesize, VAR_ABC;
     Close #filesize
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That solved Q1 and 3 for me. Is there an option for Q2? i.e. print "Hello World: and VAR_ABC using one statement? ( I am asking because I have 10 statements)

Comment: `Print #filesize, "Hello World!" & vbNewLine & VAR_ABC`