# VBA - Excel Data to .txt Format Issues

Tags: excel, vba

I am parsing parts of an Excel datasheet, copying 3 columns of number data from it to a .txt file.  All OK, except the columns in the text file end up with commas between them. Without using a 'replace' script, can I just write them correctly the first time?  `cellValue` is DIM'd as a DOUBLE

```
Open myFile For Output As #1
For i = 1 To 25
    For j = 1 To 3
        cellValue = Cells(i, j).Value
        If j = 3 Then
            Write #1, cellValue
        Else
            Write #1, cellValue,
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Close #1
```

Comment: What does "write them correctly" mean to you?  You've told us what you currently get, but not what you want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314900/writing-variable-to-a-file-using-macro

Answer (score 0):

You can `Join` the three items in each row before writing it:

```
Dim V(1 to 3) As Variant

Open myFile For Output As #1
For i = 1 To 25
    For j = 1 To 3
        V(j) = Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
    Write #1, Join(V)
Next i
```

The `Variant` type should be able to take care of the needed type conversions (assuming that they are numerical values in the cells), although if you need to force a conversion to double you could use `V(j) = CDbl(Cells(i,j).Value)`, although the `Join()` would just convert them to strings anyway.

The above code inserts spaces between the numbers. If you want some other delimiter (e.g. a semicolon) you could use something like `Join(V,";")`.

By the way, this is VBA rather than VBScript. While closely related, they are not the same languages.

Comment: John, So that works in removing the commas, but does leave each line surrounded by quotes.  Even using the CDbl command does leave the quotes.  These files end up being fed to other software which needs 3 columns of data free of anything else.

Comment: You could replace `Write` by `Print`. When I want to write files in VBA, I tend to not use `Write` or `Print` at all but instead use VBScript's `TextStream` objects -- which can be called from `VBA`. See [this](https://analystcave.com/vba-filesystemobject-fso-in-excel/vba-opentextfile/) for details.

Comment: So, that worked well.  But it does put in a carriage return after the last line, which I don't want.  Is the solution to remove it (it occurs after a known line #), or can it be prevented in the 1 st place?